# Adding a new Series based on user input after graph is loaded with existing series using the Android Plot library

Tags: android, androidplot

Can a new Series be added using Android Plot based on user action after existing series are loaded?
Currently I'm adding a new series based on user input after the inflation is successful.
But my new series is not reflecting in UI.
Is there any API to refresh the graph once I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Plot.redraw()` any time your plot changes after it's been initially displayed though.  In your case you'd call it after adding the new series.